# Jquery mixitup disrupting dropdown Menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

So here is my dilemma.

I have added the MixItUp JQuery plugin to a page. Everything works well, I was able to style it and everything. All good except my main menu's drop down menus no longer function. I have narrowed it down to the JS files but not being a JS expert I was hoping someone could provide some direction So i may address this issue.

http://amin.patbickham.com/pages/casestudies.html

Comment: Have you opened up Google Chrome Developer tab and see whats the error in the console ?

Comment: Thank you. I took a look and the only error I found was this [code]event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. [/code] DO you think this is the cause?

Comment: The menu works on the Home page .. :)

Answer (score 0):

On the page you showed , its not able to get

```
jquery.min.map GET 404 Not Found text/html  casestudies.html:39
```

Thats why you are getting JS error on Console as :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'superfish'
```

Comment: Thank for you help. The Superfish JS I had was old. I uploaded a more current one and now it works fine.